# Will Redux in React work only with Functional Components?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have been doing some learning of React and have been developing projects. I recently started of with Redux, and so, wanted to develop my next project using it. I set it up perfectly fine, and for one component in the app, I thought, why can't I have a class component in it. I tried the same and it threw up a lot of errors.

So I want to know, will react-redux only work with functional components and not class components. and if so, it would be great if you can explain why?

For example:
I can't seem to declare the selectors inside the class component. When I declare a variable as follows:

```
const play = useSelector((state) => state.play);
```

It throws the following error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
>   of a function component.

Comment: You can use redux with class components. It's unclear what your specific problem was.

Comment: I tried it and I can't seem to declare the selectors inside the class component. for ex: const play = useSelector((state) => state.play); - It throws the following error: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Comment: Yes, you can't use hooks in class components. That doesn't mean you can't use redux.

Comment: So wouldn't it be better to assume that, it is better to use redux with functional components? Sorry, I am just new with this whole thing, and I want to learn it very thoroughly.

Comment: No, why would it? The two things are completely orthogonal, you can use redux or not with either class- or function-based components.

Comment: I  guess because, the only major advantage of React Class Components was that they handled the state. Now once the state has been handled by redux, I dont see any point in declaring class components.

Comment: The replacement for class-based component state in function-based components is useState. Redux is operating at a different level.

Comment: @Pruthvi both functional & class components can handle state, class just uses a single `state` whereas you can use multiple with functional `useState`. Redux is for global "state" where you can access from any component however nested it may be without having to pass props between them. There is not really any advantage/disadvantage to using either with regards to Redux, other than the additional boilerplate when using classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You eventually got the gist of it in the comments but to to put it simply, you can use Redux with **either** class or functional components, but the way you access it use different methods.

**Functional Components:** 
`useSelector`, `useDispatch`
https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { myAction } from './myActions';

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  // connect to "play" from Redux store
  const play = useSelector((state) => state.play);
  // do stuff
  console.log(play);
}

export default MyComponent;
```

**Class Components:**
 `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)`
https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  // do stuff
  console.log(this.props.play)
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  play: state.play
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```